# Python 3 websocket client, run forever

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to write a Python 3 code, which prints out every new Dogicoin blocks, using [Dogechain Websocket API](https://dogechain.info/api/websocket) and [python websocket client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client).

```
import json
import ssl
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("wss://ws.dogechain.info/inv", sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
ws.send(json.dumps({"op":"blocks_sub"}))
while 1:
    result = ws.recv()
    print(result)
```

After a successful subscription, block updates are not coming. All I get is the following output, and nothing else. My goal is to run a function every time when a block arrives. What did I do wrong?

```
{"op": "status", "msg": "subscribed, welcome, ..."}
{"op": "status", "msg": "subscribed"}
```

Comment: I have the same issue using nodejs client, did you manage to figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread where your block function exists, and in while condition run that thread function and put some sleep time of you want, this way you can have your block data irrespective of its existence, even if it doesn't exist it'll give you blank response.

For e.g, I've done like this,
This is my thread function

```
def mail_data(self):
    mailbox = getMailBox();
    while True:
        notify('notification',mailbox.checkMailBox()) // my email library in buiilt function
        time.sleep(20)
```

and In my html page, I'm using websocket like this,

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                // on receiving messages through websocket
                var json_data = evt.data; //this will be got from that function
};
```

I hope this helps !